# VirusTotal API equivalent

Tags: api

Is there any API that allows you to query file hashes to see if they are known malicious, have been scanned before, etc?

I'm looking for something like VirusTotal, but VirusTotal is intentionally malicious towards individuals who aren't willing to spend 100,000 dollars a year for an API to look up a few hashes every day.

I want to be able to look up less than a dozen hashes at once in a 10 line python script maybe once or twice a day, so I dont have to manually copy and paste hashes into the website and check one at a time, but with the API restrictions its faster to manually copy and paste.

Unless there is another service that provides a real API which isn't maliciously restricted to 4 hashes per minute, then the only solution is to write a scraper that connects to the main website, which I try to avoid.

Comment: Huh? You might need to read again. I'm using their "free layer" with my repo, looking up quite a few hashes daily and even uploading files in an automated way. Depends on which end points you need, of course, so YMMV – but without specifying what details you're interested in, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I want to be able to look up less than a dozen hashes at once in a 10 line python script, so I dont have to manually copy and paste hashes into the website and check one at a time, but with the API restrictions its faster to manually copy and paste. But it looks like this is just too difficult to implement in 2022 so I guess I'm forced to stay with manual copy/paste, or write a program that scrapes it from the website. Virustotal explicitly states they do not care about individuals, and if you want to break free of their jail you have to pay between 10,000 and 100,000 dollars for an API key.

Comment: You sure you know how to do loops? I do that regularly for a list of files. Simplified pseudo-code: "for file in files do: submit file; sleep 30; done". Take note of the "sleep" part. There's a limit of "hits per minute", the "sleep" takes care you don't go beyond. So no problem with looking up hundreds of hashes per day. Consider an average of 2min per lookup with sleeps (to be on the absolutely safe side), you could easily make 720 files per day for free.

Comment: I don't want to wait 5 minutes for a task that should take 2 seconds (and takes 30 seconds by hand). These comments have become unproductive to the original question.